# I am trying to make an icon as button. I wants to give action like a button. I am writing code for image upload

Tags: jquery, html

I am writing a code for profile photo(image) upload. I created a camera icon for that. I tried to write code for button like action to the camera icon but failed.

Can any one please let me know how to write a code giving action to image like button? The camera icon should get action like a button for image upload. If anybody worked on that please help me to resolve this.

```
<div class="camera1" ><img id ="camera10" height="25" width="25" src="icons/camara orange.png"/> </div>
```

Comment: Does your image show ok?   And you want some code for upload file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
<button type="submit" id="download" style="display:none;"></button>
<label for="download">
    <img src="https://s22.postimg.org/ur2orci69/AS13_page_Icon_camera.png">
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="camera1" ><a href=""><img id ="camera10" height="25" width="25" src="https://s22.postimg.org/ur2orci69/AS13_page_Icon_camera.png"/></a> </div>
```